# Issue with createFulfillmentOrder Amazon MWS

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I'm getting the following error while creating an order for canadian postal code: AB T5T 6V7.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Exception' with message 'Value  for parameter DestinationAddress.PostalCode is invalid. Reason: InvalidValue.' in /Amazon/FBAOutboundServiceMWS/Client.php:970
Stack trace:
#0 /Amazon/FBAOutboundServiceMWS/Client.php(937): FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Client->_reportAnyErrors('<ErrorResponse ...', '400', Object(FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_ResponseHeaderMetadata))
#1 /Amazon/FBAOutboundServiceMWS/Client.php(178): FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Client->_invoke(Array)
#2 /Amazon/functions.inc.php(252): FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Client->createFulfillmentOrder(Object(FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_CreateFulfillmentOrderRequest))
#3 /amazon_automation.php(200): invokeCreateFulfillmentOrder(Object(FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Client), Object(FBAOutboundServiceMWS_Model_CreateFulfillmentOrderRequest))
#4 {main}
  thrown in /Amazon/FBAOutboundServiceMWS/Client.php on line 970
```

But it is working for other Zipcodes of Canada.

Can anyone help me on this if I need to change some settings in my sellercentral?

Comment: Edmonton, AB T5T 6V7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to explicitly check the state and resolve it before sending to FBA.

Comment: You should provide the code that helped you solve the issue or explain it in more detail to help others having the same problem.